# SSIS File System Task inside a ForEach Loop

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a `ForEach Loop` (File enumerator) in which I load text files into a SQL Server table. After each file is loaded I want it to be moved to another directory:

[image: ForEachLoop]

But it errors when trying to evaluate the variable containing the file name:

[image: ForEachLoop Error]

Here is the defined variable in the context of the for each loop:

[image: ForEachLoop FileName Variable]

When I disable the Move File task it runs completely and correctly although the data flow contains a C# script that uses the file name contained in the same variable:

[image: ForEachLoop DataFlow]

[image: ForEachLoop DataFlow Script Editor]

Here is where the variable is referenced in the Move File editor:

[image: ForEachLoop MoveFile Editor]

How can I make the Move File task to recognize the file name variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide some initial value to the variable so that it can clear the validation.